# Setting a buffer of 0 in Pandas dataframe.to_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Is there a way to set a buffer of '0' when using the Pandas dataframe.to_csv()?  I looked through the documentation and it appears to not allow that as an argument.  Am I overlooking something?

Edit:  I am asking because I am outputting dataframes which range in size from several hundred to many thousands of rows (always with the same 7 columns), and a later process that eventually examines the file is occasionally failing because sometimes it isn't finished being written.

I could of course introduce a delay (of 3-5 minutes), but I'd rather not arbitrarily slow down my code if I don't have to - I'd rather force the the code to wait for the completion of the output before moving on, and when writing files with open() it's nice to be able to set a buffer value of '0'.

Comment: Why do you need to do this, if you don't pass anything then a string of the output is returned

Comment: just added some more information.

Comment: @traggatmot If you only want some way for the other process to know that file creation is complete, what I did in a similar situation was create a empty file called `finished.txt` or something like that, and make the other process wait until that file has created. This way there is only a few microseconds delay and no weird lock issues. Just make sure you delete the `finished.txt` file before you begin your writing your csv.

Comment: So it can't handle writing two files at the same time?  Meaning if the order is 1) writing output.csv, 2) writing finished.txt., then 3)next process, python will make sure to finish writing output.csv before finished.txt?  So that the next process (step 3) is never started before output.csv is written?

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could implement the following.  This snippet passes a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) instance as the first argument for [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-to-csv-format), and calls [`seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```
import StringIO

#### your code here...assuming something like:
#### import pandas as pd
#### data = {"key1":"value1"}
#### dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dataframe)

buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
dataframe.to_csv(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
output = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
```

You could then manipulate `output` however you choose.